# Update Policy queries are not accounted for in cluster capacity for Query resource

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I noticed something interesting, I have a bunch of stored functions in my ADX database and each one corresponds to an update policy with a common target table. Since the data is continuously being pumped into the source tables, update policies are getting triggered and data is getting loaded to the target table. It means at any given time a bunch of instances of all the individual functions are executing (one instance per source extent) , but when I issue `.show capacity` command, it always shows me that consumed 'Queries' resource is always 0. I was expecting this number to be sufficiently big, because update policy function execution is essential a query, the query text being the function call itself. And then again multiple source extents are getting created for every table at at a time ,there will be multiple instances too , this explains why I expect a big number here. But no matter how many times I issued this command `.show capacity` , I always see consumed 'Queries' as 0. Why is this so? And where else can I see exact number of these update policy query instances running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I always see consumed 'Queries' as 0*

Queries that are executed internally by commands (e.g. by `.set-or-append` commands, `.export` commands, or as part of update policies triggered by commands like `.ingest`) aren't counted under the `Queries` capacity.

The commands that invoke them adhere to the capacity constraints of the virtual resource (e.g. `Ingestion`) they fall under.

---

> *where else can I see exact number of these update policy query instances running?*

The aforementioned queries (that are run internally, by commands) aren't currently exposed to you as of this writing.

Using `.show table * policy update` you can see the update policies you have defined, and derive which queries are being run when you ingest into a specific table.